# @onetomany with foreign key

Tags: jpa, one-to-many

I have two table like these :

1) table server_type :

```
server_type_id : number 

server_type_name : nvarchar
```

2) table server :

```
server_id:number

server_IP:nvarchar2

servername :nvarchar2

server_type_id:number
```

I want to create  server table with `@OneToMany` with `server_type_id` foreign key with referenced from `server_type`

I don't know how to do it , all of example and question here is opposite of this

Comment: @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="server_type_id", referencedColumnName="server_type_id")
    public List<ServerType> getServerType() {
        return serverType;
    }

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit your question. The code you poasted makes no sense. The tables imply that one ServerType has many Servers, or that many servers can have the same ServerType. Your code tells JPA that one server has several ServerTypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this ??. May be we can help if you can post some code :)

```
      public class Server {

          @ManyToOne            
          @JoinColumn(name = "server_type_id")
          private ServerType serverType;    
     }

       public class ServerType {

           @OneToMany(mappedBy = "serverType")
           private Collection<Server> servers;  
       }
```

Comment: @OneToMany ServerType.server must be a collection of some kind (and probably be named servers)!

Comment: Thanks fixed it :). I thought of posting some sample code, i didn't tried it. Lesson: Never post by code assumptions ;)

Comment: I've tried it before,it's not the answer .
you know i want to have OneToMany  in server entity with server_type_id foreign key refrenced from server_type entity the answer of @Kalher is the opposit it's create server_id in server_type entity , but i want server_type_id in server entity

Comment: @omidhaghighatgoo: what you're asking is impossible. How could a single column in server reference multiple IDs of server type? It just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: my server table know the key of server type and servertype doesn't need to know about server table , i show my ERD , why it's impossible

Answer (score 1):

Your `@OneToMany` relationship can be achieved

1. using join table
2. without join table

In your case you can use second option and here is an example (you are talking about examples)

```
class UserDetails {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
  private Vehicle vehicle;

 //Other fields

}

class Vehicle {

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
      private UserDrtails user;

     //other fields
}
```

Comment: i need something like this :
@OneToMany
@ForeignKey(name=server_type_id ,referenced=server_type_id)

but with right syntax

Comment: your example is exactly the oposite thing that i want , it creates server_id in server_type table but iwant to create server_type_id in server table 
tnx

Comment: do you have any idea ?

Comment: Foreign key will be in the table where you use `@JoinColumn` so in this case it will be in Vehicle table, if you want reverse just reverse them (including `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`) that is use `@JoinColumn` in UserDetails and mappedBy in Vehicle. Now apply same thing to your classe.